# Software/platform that will produce custom investor reports based on their investments and other parameters

Tags: reporting

Trying to find a software - ideally a SaaS online platform - that will be able to create custom reports for investors based on parameters like investment portfolio, amounts, tax etc.

Here's an example:

Say we manage a portfolio of 6 apartment rentals. We have a number of investors that have invested varying amounts in each, several or all apartments. We pay out yearly dividends on each apartment and each investor gets their share of the profits.

Instead of sending 6 separate reports on each apartment to the investors invested in them, we would like to find a tool where we could provide the input (cash yield % per apartment, share of profits per investor, tax) and get either custom made consolidated reports or a platform to access them, that each investor can log in and only see the apartments they invested in, and their share of the profits.

For example, Investor John owns 10% of apartment 1, 20% of apartment 2 and 40% of apartment 5. We would input that total 2021 profit for apartment 1 is $10k, for 2 it's 20k and for 3 it's 30k, and the output for John would be the reports for these 3 apartments, the total profits per apartment and his share ($1k from app1, $4k from app2, $12k from app3), and tax if applicable.

Tried something like Google DataStudio but it did not seem as intuitive or customizable. Something that looks nice would be welcome. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1):

This may not be a complete answer, but long so entering here.
You could probably use a stock/shares platform that enables bookings per account for this.

- Treat each property as a customised "stock" or "security".
- The percentages of property owned as units of stock. Each person should have own account.
- Amount invested as amount paid for stock.
- Then value of property entered daily or quarterly or as often as you want by entering valuation as "price" manually.

Try it out in any stock software you find e.g. [Portfolio Performance](https://www.portfolio-performance.info/en/), [GhostFolio](https://github.com/ghostfolio/ghostfolio) - you will have to confirm if multiple accounts allowed.

There are also specialised programs for property investment out there. You may have to search online.